# How can I automatically assign a free port for socket connection?

Tags: python, sockets

I am using Python for a basic socket program.

On the server side:

```
port = 3135
c.bind('0.0.0.0',port)
```

On the client side:

```
port = 3135
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
```

However, I need to manually change the `port` variable every time the program throws an `OSError` (when the port is not free)

How can I automatically select a port that is free?

Comment: No you don't. You just need to set SO_REUSEADDR before you bind the server socket. And not use a port that is already reserved. This one is.

Comment: And the program can only throw that error once, not 'every time'.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also, yes the program can only throw it once, I meant to say that every time I changed the port manually, the code would throw that error

Answer (score 3):

The python docs don't seem to mention it explicitly, but the normal procedure to do this with sockets is:

1. Before listening, the server binds its socket to port 0, which causes the system to choose a free port.
2. The server calls `getsockname` to get the address the socket is bound to, including the actual port number
3. The server somehow publishes the port number where clients can see it
4. Clients then connect to that specific port.